# Adding text fields using Javascript but values keep erasing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form ive created as follows

```
<label>Search:</label>
        <form name="findrecipe" action="#">

            <input type="radio" name="search" id="search_name" value="name" checked>Name
            <input type="radio" name="search" id="search_ing" value="ingredients">Ingredients<br/>
            <input type="text" name="searchBox" onchange="javascript:addBox(this.value);"/>
            <div id="search">
            </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

Im adding a box each time the field is changed using the java script code

```
function addBox(formVal){
    var temp = this.value;
    alert(formVal);
    if(document.getElementById("search_ing").checked){
        document.getElementById("search").innerHTML += "<br/><input type='text' name='searchBox' onchange='javascript:addBox();'/>";
        this.value = temp;
    }
}
```

As you can see Ive tried to re input the value so that way it does not clear the values in the previous boxes but im definitely having issues. How can i add text fields with out clearing the rest?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try appending new elements to the container rather than appending the HTML markup.

```
$('.container').append($('br')).append($('input'));
```

jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Upvote for appending to the DOM as oppposed to HTML injection

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're passing in the form value, but then ignoring it aside from alert()ing it.

change

```
var temp = this.value;
```

to

```
var temp = formVal;
```

and change

```
this.value = temp;
```

to

```
document.getElementById("search").value = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you're not using any jQuery, you've tagged the question jQuery, so I've taken the liberty of using jQuery...

I'd simplify the html to this:

```
<label>Search:</label>
<form name="findrecipe" action="#">
    <input type="radio" name="search" id="search_name" value="name" checked />Name
    <input type="radio" name="search" id="search_ing" value="ingredients" />Ingredients<br/>
    <input class="searchbox" type="text" name="searchBox" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form> ​
```

with the following javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').on('change', '.searchbox', function() {
       $('form').append('<br/><input class="searchbox" type="text" name="searchBox" />');
    });
});​
```

The jQuery will then add a new input whenever someone changes the value of an existing input, but without altering the existing ones, so all existing values are preserved.

There's a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cm5Ug/).

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that you're not setting the input's value, like you think you are.

In the instance of

```
this.value = temp;
```

"this" is referring to the DOMWindow, not the input, so you are trying to set the value of the window, not the input.

My solution (Quick HTML Injection hack way) would be something along the lines of

```
function addBox(formVal){
    var temp = formVal;
    //alert(formVal);
    if(document.getElementById("search_ing").checked){

        document.getElementById("search").innerHTML += "<br/><input type='text' name='searchBox' onchange='addBox(this.value);' value='"+formVal+"'/>";
        //this.value = temp;
    }
}
```

If I had more time, I would use something a little more elegant like (this is not tested, so it won't work out of box)

```
var newINput = document.createElement("input");
newINput.type='text';
newINput.value= "";
newInput.name= some unique name ;

document.getElementById('search').appendChild(newINput);
```