# What keeps erasing the text input value on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, focus

I realize I'm almost replicating a excel **table**; in a plugin, the intended behavior is:
when a  is clicked a  within it containing a value is replaced with an  that get's the same value and so can be edited. It works but the problem is when clicking the newly created text input the value is reset or erased to ''.

I don't know what does that, I've tried the event listener, I've tried to .unbind focus, click, on click, on focus because it seems reclicking the text box fires something that erases it. I used F12 event listener and stepped into everything but i think it might be something jquery does on its own by default, but i would like to know if anyonw knows what is causing this behavior.

```
$( "td" ).click(function(event)
{   
    var value = $( this ).text(); // gets the text inside section inside the td
    var column = $( this ).get( 0 ).id; //gets id="" of the td that is how I indentify columns
    var parent = $( this ).parent().get( 0 ).id; //gets the id of the row <tr id="x"><td id=">

    if( column == "a" || column == "b" )
    {
        return;
    } 
    else if ( column == "d" || column == "c" )
    {
        $( this ).children().replaceWith( '<input type=email value=' + value + '>' );
        $( this ).children().focus();
    }
    else
    {
        $( this ).children().replaceWith( '<input type=text value="' + value + '">' );
        $( this ).children().focus();           
    }

    $( this ).children().focusout(function(event){
        var new_value = $( this ).val();
        $( this ).parent().addClass( "edited" );
        $( this ).replaceWith( '<section>' + new_value + '</section>' );
});
```

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342375/adding-text-fields-using-javascript-but-values-keep-erasing) but it does not solve my question nor fix my problem. They suggested he .append the new html instead of injecting it. So maybe there are problems with using the ".replaceWith()?"... idk, i've searched everywhere.

Comment: Can you provide he HTML to go with the JavaScript code? Or put an example in jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qzbrzm4x/1/ There you can see the behavior, also when selecting the cursor area, it stops at spaces, i've noticed, any thoughts on that too?

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing the cell with an input which has value={the text}/
Therefore .text() will now return nothing.

Example:

```
html:
<table>
<td id="only_text"><p>some text</p></td>
<td id='input_text'><input type="text" value="some text 2"/></td>
</table>

js:
$(function(){
    console.log($('#only_text').text());
    console.log($('#input_text').text() +'');
})
```

You can see the example in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qzbrzm4x/ (open your console and run)

Comment: True, true.... So each new click into the <input> is triggering the <td> click, because it's inside the <td> (obv). How can I go about solving this then? I'm new to js so I'm used to code being complied and run at once in a linear fashion. Thus I never imagined another or the same td would be triggered without the whole function being completed (so noobish)

Comment: you can check the children on click, and see if it's an input, and if so, do something else (i.e. do nothing, return from the function)... The solution is up to you.
You can change the input back to the text when you leave focus from the input too, which will give you a nice little lifecycle for the cell - it will only be an input temporarily, while being edited